# Encrypt Decrypt using Dnscrypt on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, security, configuration, dnscrypt-proxy

Is there a good guide for encrypting decrypting using Dnscrypt on Ubuntu?

Comment: There is a help center, if you are unsure how to post a question here. http://askubuntu.com/help

Comment: Does not work. The 3rd command. This is the result.
sudo apt-get install dnscrypt-proxy
E: Impossible find packet dnscrypt-proxy

Answer (score 3):

You can install Dnscrypt using [**ppa:shnatsel/dnscrypt**](https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/dnscrypt) PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shnatsel/dnscrypt

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dnscrypt-proxy
```

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked after i did this and set my dns as 127.0.0.2

Comment: This ppa does not have one for 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it working with OpenDNS

I got it to work with DNSCrypt.org client

- libsodium4_0.4.5-0~trusty5_amd64.deb
- dnscrypt-proxy-1.4.2.tar.gz
- install them with gdebi-gtk

Nether in official ppa yet for Ubuntu 14.04 had to download them from:

- https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt/+files/libsodium4_0.4.5-0~trusty5_amd64.deb
- https://launchpad.net/~shnatsel/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt/+files/dnscrypt-proxy_1.4.0-0~oldconf2%2Bsaucy1_amd64.deb

Set DNS address 127.0.0.2 network tools KDE

```
sudo start it sudo service ddclient restart 
sudo service network-manager restart
```

---

```
$ dig debug.opendns.com txt

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> debug.opendns.com txt 
;; global options: +cmd 
;; Got answer: 
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57152 
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 7, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: 
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096 
;; QUESTION SECTION: 
;debug.opendns.com. IN TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION: 
debug.opendns.com. 0 IN TXT "server 5.ash" 
debug.opendns.com. 0 IN TXT "flags 20 0 2F6 0" 
debug.opendns.com. 0 IN TXT "originid 26933670" 
debug.opendns.com. 0 IN TXT "actype 2" 
debug.opendns.com. 0 IN TXT "bundle 6932830" 
debug.opendns.com. 0 IN TXT "source 66.168.29.120:54722" 
debug.opendns.com. 0 IN TXT "dnscrypt enabled (71447764594D3377)"

;; Query time: 58 msec 
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) 
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 04 12:46:15 CST 2015 
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 265
```